# Struggling in drawing State machine diagram

Tags: uml, state-machine

Hey there I'm trying to draw state machine diagram for this scenario but It's missing lots of information. If someone here could help out with it.

The Scenario

1. Tourists will start the journey by selecting the trip using the
   Automated Ticketing system (ATS).
2. The Automated Ticketing System (ATS) will display the trip details.
3. This Trip details will include the seat-number and destination.
4. Based on provided trip details, the ATS will compute payment.
5. The tourist has the option to pay the payment by cash or credit
   card.
6. If the tourist will insert a wrong amount of cash, the ATS will
   display "Insert More Cash" message on the screen until the correct
   amount will be inserted.
7. If payment by card was selected by the tourist, the ATS will perform
   two parallel tasks. It will validate the expiration date of the card
   and check the credit balance. If card is accepted, the bank will
   authorize the payment and will update the account of the tourist.
   However, if card is not accepted or invalid, the ATS will again ask
   for payment option (back to step 5) from the tourist.
8. After payment is complete, the ticket and receipt are printed by the
   ATS.
9. Cash payment might result in some change, so the change is also
   dispensed by the ATS. The tourist will then get the ticket and the
   change.
10. ATS will display the message "Transaction Complete" at the end of
     the transaction.

My Drawing:

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're trying to use state machine diagram rather than activity diagram or sequence diagram? State machine focuses on states rather than actions that has to be performed. I don't say it's impossible to build one in your case but I want to be sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: I concur with @Ister. The reading of this diagram is not that of a state machine but of an AD.

Comment: @ThomasKilian  is there any thing that i can do so this scenario can be used to draw state machine ,package ,block definition and requirment diagram. because im using it to draw all the diagrams.

Comment: @Ister i already draw the AD and Sd also use case. But i want to use this scenario to draw also other diagrams.

Comment: The SD focuses on states. Things like `waiting', 'polling', 'receiving', `waiting for transaction completion` etc. Your "states" are activities.This is a fundamental difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I try to give you some hints. A state machine is always created for a single class, not the overall system under consideration. So let's assume the ATS is a single class (in reality it will probably be more a component consisting of several classes). Now this ATS will in the beginning be idle. It is triggered somehow when a trip is selected. It then has to complete the journey details. It waits for payment and finally it will spit out a ticket. Now (basically!) the state machine looks like this:

[image]

This is a scaffold and it was done without reading the details above. Note that instead of the `cancel` transitions you could use a general exception from an interruptible region which eventually clears payments. In practice you would likely do that since a cancellation should (from a user perspective) be possible at any point. A time out of course would also be possible (what if already some cash had been paid?).

Also I did not include the `do/entry/exit` actions. For the cash this would be something like `add new cash sum` so we know when enough money has been paid.

Comment: Software used for Diagram?

Comment: @JamesB Enterprise Architect